# replace json array with object using regex

Tags: regex, json, regex-negation

with asp.net API i get json array from API service.But there is deserialization problems.For example response sometimes array for Supplier sometimes it returns one item(just object not object array)

my response string contains that object array

```
      "Suppliers":{"size":"2","Supplier":
[
{"id":"3","chainCode":"WV"},{"id":"13","chainCode":"EP"}
]}
```

i want to convert that to this

```
 "Suppliers":{"size":"2","Supplier":{"id":"3","chainCode":"WV"}}
```

i want to delete all Suppliers item from respone except one item 
so i delete that  [ ] and then delete items with regex but it does not work true
what is problem with my regex?

```
EnEskiData1 = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(EnEskiData1, "(\"Supplier\"\\:\\{(.*?)\\})", "\"Supplier\":[{$2}]");
```

Comment: Is there a reason you can't deserialize, modify, and reserialize the json string? It's a specification literally made for this sort of thing.

Comment: i am using this dll Newtonsoft.Json.dll, v6.0.0.0  i use expedia API...their service sometimes return array,sometimes they return one object for same property.....i tried to solve that but i did not handle...i write their support team but there is no solution....

Comment: You should still deserialize and then check what type you get. If you want, you can create a dynamic object to hold the data, too, though I wouldn't prefer it.

Comment: this is very very big system......i will convert it later.But now i will use regex as a workaround solution